# Convert Blade If Else to Vue If Else

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I have an `if else` condition in Blade and I want to convert it to a Vue `if else`

```html
@if (Auth::user()->avatar != null)
    <img src="{{ URL::to('storage/app/public') . '/' . Auth::user()->avatar }}"
        class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">
@endif
@if (Auth::user()->avatar == null)
    @if (Auth::user()->gender == 'Male')
        <img src="{{ URL::asset('public/bower_components/admin-lte/dist/img/fb-male.jpg') }}"
            class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">
    @else
        <img src="{{ URL::asset('public/bower_components/admin-lte/dist/img/female-fb.jpg') }}"
            class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">
    @endif
@endif
```

Comment: StackOverflow not a free service for writing codes, please check [how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you should store your data in vue data variables and use `v-if` and `v-else` for implementing vue conditions.

Comment: @Joseph Don't need your answer. Thanks! I got the another answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert the `@if` branches in your blade file, use `<template>`s with [`v-if`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if)/[`v-else`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-else):

```html
<template v-if="{{ Auth::user()->avatar != null }}">
    <img src="{{ URL::to('storage/app/public') . '/' . Auth::user()->avatar }}"
        class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">
</template>
<template v-else>
    <template v-if="{{ Auth::user()->gender == 'Male' }}">
        <img src="{{ URL::asset('public/bower_components/admin-lte/dist/img/fb-male.jpg') }}"
            class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">
    </template>
    <template v-else>
        <img src="{{ URL::asset('public/bower_components/admin-lte/dist/img/female-fb.jpg') }}"
            class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">
    </template>
</template>
```